# Sequelize find data and if it exists then update it

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, endpoint

I am really new to `sequelize` and I am looking for a way to check if data exist and then update it. I am using `models.Booker.findAll` followed by booker id, where it will look for booker id and if exist it returns the data. If the returned value is greater than 0, then only it should update the customer values following `models.Customer.update`.

As to get values we need to use `router.get` and to update values we need to use `router.put`. Is there a way we can use `router.get` first and if it returns data then use `router.put` to update the data?

```
router.get(
    "/customer/email/:email_id/phone/:phone_number/booker_id/:booker_id",
    (req, res) => {
      models.Booker.findAll({
        where: {
          id: req.params.booker_id
        },
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // res.send(data);
        if(data.length > '0'){
          
          models.Customer.update({
            where: {
              test: null,
              email: req.params.email_id,
              phone: req.params.phone_number
            },
          })
          .then((sendValue) => {
            res.send(sendValue);
          })
          .catch((error) => res.json(error));
        }
        else{
          res.send(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => res.json(error));
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to update the booker table you'll have to use helper functions to update your customer table

```
async function getBookerById(params) {
  console.log("getting booker By Id:" + params)
  const booker = await db.Booker.findAll({ where: { id: params} });
  return booker;
}

async function updateBooker(id, params, userId) {
  console.log("params: " + params)

  const booker = await getBookerById(id);

  if (booker.length > 0) { //you may have to call your model here 
    const customer = await db.Customer.findone(where key: value);
    // copy params to booker and save
    Object.assign(customer, params);
    await customer.save();
    return omitHash(customer.get());
  } else {
    throw "error"
  }
}
```